# How to show all intent-filter of a component in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

As the title says, I want to know all intent-filter(s) and actions inside it of a component like activity, receiver or service.

For example in AM.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.samsung.longuni.receivers.WakeServiceUpReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Is there any way that in my application I can list up all actions in a intent-filter of a component of a certain application.

Comment: do you mean [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_INTENT_FILTERS)?

Comment: I meant, for example a receiver of other app. I want to write a app to list all actions side intent-filter of that receiver. It's programmatic not opening AndroidManifest.xml to see